# Two branches not covered in a for-loop

Tags: apex

I am having issues on covering two branches of a for-loop in a test class, this is the actual test method class;

```
@isTest
static void testGetSummaryWithAllInactive()
{
    List<Account> lstAccount = TestDataFactory.createMultipleAcc(1);
    Account acc = [Select id,PersonContactId From Account Where Id = :lstAccount[0].id];
    Account acct = new Account(Name = 'Acct New', Tracking_Displayed__c = 'GTM');
    List<User> lstuser = TestDataFactory.createUsers(1,'Tenant - EVS QA','tenant@mail.com',acc.PersonContactId);
    Property__c pro = new Property__c(Name = 'TestProperty');
    insert pro;
    List<Hover_Help__kav> hovers = TestDataFactory.createHovers(1, 'Address');
    List<Contract> lstContracts = TestDataFactory.createContracts(1,acc.id,pro.id);
    Contract singleCont = new Contract(Status = 'Draft', AccountId = acc.Id, StartDate = Date.newInstance(2024, 03, 06));
    insert singleCont;
    lstContracts.add(singleCont);
    TenantComponentPreReporting.Rental[] rent = new TenantComponentPreReporting.Rental[]{};
    rent.add(new TenantComponentPreReporting.Rental(singleCont));
    Hover_Help__kav hover1 = new Hover_Help__kav(Icon_Name__c = 'Address', Title = 'Hover Test 1', urlName = 'www-hovertest1-com');
    insert hover1;
    Hover_Help__kav hover2 = new Hover_Help__kav(Icon_Name__c = 'Landlord', Title = 'Hover Test 2', urlName = 'www-hovertest2-com');
    insert hover2;
    Hover_Help__kav hover3 = new Hover_Help__kav(Icon_Name__c = 'Rent', Title = 'Hover Test 3', urlName = 'www-hovertest3-com');
    insert hover3;
    //KbManagement.PublishingService.publishArticle(hover1.KnowledgeArticleId , true);
    
    System.runAs(lstuser[0]){
        Test.startTest();
        try{
        TenantComponentPreReporting.Rentals result = TenantComponentPreReporting.getSummary();
        
        result.showGtm = false;
        result.showPartnerize = false;
        result.allInactive = true;
                    
        System.assertEquals(false, result.showGtm, 'Now is false');
        System.assertEquals(false, result.showPartnerize, 'Also false');
        System.assertEquals(true, result.allInactive, 'Is true, all Inactive');
        System.assert('Address', hover1.Icon_Name__c, 'True');
        System.assertEquals('Landlord', hover2.Icon_Name__c, 'Correct');
        System.assertEquals('Rent', hover3.Icon_Name__c, 'Correct');
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.debug('Exception catched: ' + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            Test.stopTest();
        }
      }
   
}
```

And this is the method class:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static Rentals getSummary() {

    User runningUser = Util.userForComponent();
    DataProvider provider = new DataProvider();
    Contract[] leases = provider.getLeases(runningUser.AccountId);
    Hover_Help__kav[] hovers = provider.getHoverHelp();
    Rental[] rents = new Rental[0];
    System.debug(hovers);

    for (Contract lease : leases) {
        if (lease.Status != 'Dead' && lease.Status != 'Inactive') {
            rents.add(new Rental(lease));
        }
    }

    Rentals result = new Rentals();
    result.rentals = rents;
    // result.rentals[0].isCurrent = true;
    result.showGtm = false;
    result.showPartnerize = false;

    if (rents.size() <= 0 && leases.size() > 0) {
        result.allInactive = true;
    } else {
        result.allInactive = false;
    }

    addActivitiesToRentals(result, leases, runningUser.AccountId);

    for (Hover_Help__kav hover : hovers) {

        String icon = hover.Icon_Name__c;

        if (icon == 'Address') {
            result.help1 = hover.Content__c;
        } else if (icon == 'Landlord') {
            result.help2 = hover.Content__c;
        } else if (icon == 'Rent') {
            result.help3 = hover.Content__c;
        }

    }

    // added trackers to the page
    if (leases.size() > 0) {

        Account acct = leases[0].Account;
        String[] presentations = provider.presentations(runningUser.AccountId);
        Set<String> trackers = new Set<String>();

        if (acct.Tracking_Displayed__c != null) {
            String[] existing = acct.Tracking_Displayed__c.split(';');
            trackers.addAll(existing);
        }

        if (presentations.contains('GTM')) {
            result.showGtm = true;
        }

        if (presentations.contains('Partnerize') && acct.Recurly_Initial_Invoice_Id__pc != null) {
            // result.showPartnerize = true;
            result.showPartnerize = false;

            /* Partnerize tracking event has been moved to fire when an account is reported

            String coupon = null;
            if (String.isNotBlank(acct.Account_Coupons__pc)) {
                coupon = acct.Account_Coupons__pc;
            } else if (String.isNotBlank(acct.Subscription_Coupons__pc)) {
                coupon = acct.Subscription_Coupons__pc;
            }

            String clickref = null;
            if (String.isNotBlank(acct.clickref__pc)) {
              clickref = acct.clickref__pc;
            }

            String[] url = new String[0];
            url.add('https://prf.hn');
            url.add('conversion');
            url.add('campaign:1011l763');  // old value = 1101l545
            if (clickref != null) {
                url.add('clickref:' + clickref);
            }
            url.add('conversionref:' + acct.Recurly_Initial_Invoice_Id__pc);
            if (coupon != null) {
                url.add('voucher:' + coupon);
            } else {
                url.add('voucher:');
            }
            url.add('customertype:new');

            String[] part = new String[0];
            part.add('category:SIGNUP');
            part.add('sku:TENANT');
            part.add('value:' + acct.Recurly_Initial_Invoice_Amount__pc);
            part.add('quantity:1');

            String fullurl = String.join(url, '/') + '/[' + String.join(part,'/') + ']';
            System.debug(fullurl);
            result.partnerizeUrl = fullurl;
            */
        }

        if (result.showGtm || result.showPartnerize) {
            Account acct1 = new Account();
            acct1.Id = acct.Id;
            trackers.addAll(presentations);
            acct1.Tracking_Displayed__c = provider.toMultiValuePicklist(trackers);
            provider.saveAccount(acct1);
        }
    }

    return result;

}
```

And here it is an image of the result when I run the test

[image]

I did not write the class or test, I am assigned to update the test to write "real data". Thank you in advance!

Comment: Remove the try-catch in the unit test. You're likely swallowing an unexpected exception.

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox thank you for your comment. I just removed them and still the same error

Comment: I'd look into this line: `Hover_Help__kav[] hovers = provider.getHoverHelp();` and see whether it returns all 4 records mocked in the testmethod. If not, then perhaps the hover1-2-3 records are missing some values for the `getHoverHelp` method to find them